# Laravel pagination without style

Tags: css, laravel-5

Below is my code:

```
<tbody>
                        @foreach($posts as $post)

                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ $post->id }}</th>                            
                                <td>{{ $post->title }}</td>
                                <td>{{ substr($post->body, 0, 50) }} {{ strlen($post->body) > 50 ? "..." : "" }}</td>
                                <td>{{ date('M j,Y h:i a',strtotime($post->created_at)) }}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="{{ route('posts.show', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">View</a>
                                    <a href="{{ route('posts.edit', $post->id) }}" class="btn btn-delete btn-sm">Edit</a>                                  
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="text-center">
                    {{ $posts->links() }}
                </div>
```

And below is the code in controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = Post::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);

    return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts);
}
```

In spite of this, i do not get proper styling! 
[Bootstrap styles not applied. See the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHsTq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This was the issue with new Bootstrap version 4.1 with Laravel's latest version.

I tried with the earlier version of bootstrap and it is resolved now.